# restricting users by ip and number of login attempts in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I want to restrict a user by the number of attempts he makes, but I am not sure if to do it with javascript or php..and how exactly.
(How do I save data between the same form page request. Is it by using a global variable or is it best by using a session?);
Also, how can I ban people by their ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it by PHP.

Do a MySQL table `attemptLog`

```
+------+------+------+
|  id  |  ip  | date |
+------+------+------+
```

Every time a login attempt fail you add the IP to `attemptLog`.
To log in you need a correct username and password (ofc) AND max ie 10 login attempts the last 24h.

To do that you can run `SELECT count(ip) AS loginAttempts FROM attemptLog WHERE ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] AND date < $today - 24h` then check if `loginAttempts` is more then 10.

**Banning**

To ban a user you can save their IP and check if it isset, if it is set show "You are banned", else show the normal page.

Comment: Banning IPs at the PHP level is bad. nothing prevents the IP from still hammering on the server and causing a DoS. Better to block at the webserver or firewall level.

Comment: @MarcB Then you need access to the server.

Comment: To save space you can use `INET_ATON()` (MySQL function, google it) and then use `int` you save space. Else if you are lazy you use `varchar(15)`. Ie `INSERT INTO ... VALUE(INET_ATON($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])`. And then to get the IP back you use `SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) AS ip FROM ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Always do things like this from PHP - Javascript is client-side and can be easily manipulated (disabling Javascript completely would work to get around something like this). Also, Javascript does not know your IP.

You can get the IP address of the client in PHP from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. In order to track this you will need a database. So when a failed login happens, log it in a table. Something like `INSERT INTO failed_logins (user, ip) VALUES ('$username','{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}')`. Then check how many times the login has failed with something like `SELECT count(*) as attempts FROM failed_logins WHERE ip = '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}'` - if `attempts` is >= your limit, `INSERT INTO banned_ips (ip) VALUES ('{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}')`.

And to check if a client is banned, at the beginning of processing each request do somthing like `SELECT * FROM banned_ips WHERE ip = '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}'` - if there is a row in the table with that IP, handle the request as banned.

Answer (score 1):

JS has nothing to do here.
as well as global variables and, especially - sessions.

> How do I save data between the same form page request

you have a plenty of choices - a file, a database, a shared memory. I'd suggest a database.

> how can I ban people by their ip?

check their IP and then do whatever you mean under "ban"?

Comment: What's the big thing you have against sessions?

Comment: @Mike Well in this instance, a session could easily be spoofed. Just clear your cookies, and you have started a new session. Using sessions for this would be so easy to compromise as to make it pointless.

Comment: However the question regarding sessions was `How do I save data between the same form page request`. I think sessions would be a viable and well-accepted solution for that.

Comment: can I use sessions to follow where the user clicks in the site or navigates..or is it not secure

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it on your server. If you do it in JavaScript, an attacker could just modify this.

Global variables don't survive one page call. A session would be possible, but the attacker could stop it, too.

Store the IP address with a timestamp and a failed tries counter in your database. Whenever one tries to login, pull the counter for this ip address combined with `current time - time in which you want to limit tries`. If you find an entry, check if there were to much tries and deny login. If not, check credentials - if user is validated, reset the counter, if not, increment by one and update timer to current time.

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions on SO

[Best way to limit (and record) login attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580534/best-way-to-limit-and-record-login-attempts)

[What is the best Distributed Brute Force countermeasure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479233/what-is-the-best-distributed-brute-force-countermeasure)

[Limiting the number of failed login attemps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357609/limiting-the-number-of-failed-login-attemps)