# Better method of stopping bruteforcing?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I throttle user login attempts in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090910/how-can-i-throttle-user-login-attempts-in-php)

I have a system that will automatically deny anyone access to login for fifteen minutes after they have failed three login attempts. I'm curious to know if there's a better method of stopping bruteforcing without having to use this system which can be a pain to my users?

Thanks.

Comment: Block IP - create a db table to store IP when failed attempt - After certain number of attempts show Captcha

Comment: A captcha would work, but its also very annoying for real users!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090910/how-can-i-throttle-user-login-attempts-in-php

Comment: @DaveP is right. The accepted answer to that question isn't actually the best, but there are good ones there.